# Using Jquery background to change css - How to Allow only one link at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a list of URLs that get highlighted when you click, the problem is only one link should be highlighted at any one time.

I'm able to get the reset button working. used `removeAttr) - $("a").removeAttr("style")` - (is there any negatives to doing it this way?)

But I can't get it to be only do one highlight at a time.

Could someone help me with an example code of making only one link highlighted at one time? Right now, it's possible to highlight multiple links.

I was able to make an example on Jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/M3vVw/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend doing it this way: create a CSS rule and apply it to the element you click on, removing the same style from all links first.

**jQuery**

```
$("a").click(function () {
    $('a').removeClass('back');
    $(this).addClass('back');
});
$("#btn").click(function () {
    $("a").removeClass("back")
});
```

**CSS**

```
.back {
    background-color: #ff3fff;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/M3vVw/5/)**

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `addClass()` (as [adeneo already suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15975131/82548)), but if you *must* use `attr()`:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.css("backgroundColor", "#ff3fff").closest('li').siblings().find('a').attr('style', '');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M3vVw/6/).

Or:

```
$('a').click(function(){
    var that = $(this);
    that.css("backgroundColor", "#ff3fff").closest('li').siblings().find('a').removeAttr('style');
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/M3vVw/9/).

Do remember that using `attr()`/`removeAttr()` is incredibly destructive and requires *much* more work and maintenance (you have to explicitly restructure the CSS of *each* of the styled element's properties *every* time); `addClass()`/`removeClass()` is far more efficient, since it contains all the styling externally, where it's easy to add/remove that styling to the element when needed.

References:

- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`removeAttr()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).
- [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$("a").click(function()
{
      $(this).css("backgroundColor", "#ff3fff");
      $("a").not($(this)).removeAttr("style");
});

$("#btn").click(function(){
   $("a").removeAttr("style")
});
```

Comment: No need for the `each()` loop.

Comment: Correct, I just copied his script from the fiddle. I changed my answer

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/M3vVw/10/)**</kbd>

CSS:

```
a.active{
    background:#ff3fff;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function removeActive(){
    $("a").removeClass("active");
}

$("a").click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    removeActive();
    $(this).addClass("active");
});

$("#btn").click(removeActive);
```